# What precisely is the regex pattern that Hibernate validator employes for @Email?

Tags: hibernate-validator

Versions:

```
hibernate-validator: 6.2.0.Final (from mvnrepository.com)
```

If needs be, you can peruse [relevant docs at jboss.org](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/6.2/api/).

I've discovered that out-of-the-box that Hibernate validator (through the `@Email` annotation) supports validation of E-mail addresses (that is, for strings that should house valid E-mail addresses).

QUESTION: does anyone know the default regexp that the Hibernate Validator 6.2 employs for `@Email` validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### From the [hibernate-validator source code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/a15a1846e17d505818207bcf1adcfd271e1df530/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/AbstractEmailValidator.java#L35):

> - Checks that a given character sequence (e.g. string) is a well-formed email address.
> - The specification of a valid email can be found in [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) and one can come up with a regular expression matching  [all valid email addresses](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) as per specification. However, as this [article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) discusses it is not necessarily practical to implement a 100% compliant email validator. This implementation is a trade-off trying to match most email while ignoring for example emails with double quotes or comments.

```java
private static final int MAX_LOCAL_PART_LENGTH = 64;

private static final String LOCAL_PART_ATOM = "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~\u0080-\uFFFF-]";
private static final String LOCAL_PART_INSIDE_QUOTES_ATOM = "(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*.(),<>\\[\\]:;  @+/=?^_`{|}~\u0080-\uFFFF-]|\\\\\\\\|\\\\\\\")";
/**
 * Regular expression for the local part of an email address (everything before '@')
 */
private static final Pattern LOCAL_PART_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
        "(?:" + LOCAL_PART_ATOM + "+|\"" + LOCAL_PART_INSIDE_QUOTES_ATOM + "+\")" +
                "(?:\\." + "(?:" + LOCAL_PART_ATOM + "+|\"" + LOCAL_PART_INSIDE_QUOTES_ATOM + "+\")" + ")*", CASE_INSENSITIVE
);
```

##### See also [the regex for the domain part](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/a15a1846e17d505818207bcf1adcfd271e1df530/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/util/DomainNameUtil.java#L62).